# Create database inside Azure Cosmos DB account with RBAC

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, rbac, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-java-sdk, azure-service-principal

I use java version 4 SDK for azure cosmos db. I want to create database inside azure cosmos db account with service principal, not with masterkey.

I assigned to service principal `DocumentDB Account Contributor` and `Cosmos DB Operator` built-in-role definitions, according to this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cosmos-db-operator

I was not able to create CosmosAsyncClient, until I added new custom role, which just contains reading metadata. Above mentioned built-in-role definitions do not contain it...

```
 TokenCredential ServicePrincipal = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .authorityHost("https://login.microsoftonline.com")
            .tenantId(tenant_here)
            .clientId(clientid_here)
            .clientSecret(secret_from_above_client)
            .build();

 client = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                            .endpoint(AccountSettings.HOST)
                            .credential(ServicePrincipal)
                            .buildAsyncClient();
```

After I added this role, client was created, but I am not able to create database instance and also container inside it as next step. In access control I can see that roles are assigned so service principal is correct here.

What is more, when firstly I create database and container with master key and then I want to read/write data using service principal, it works (obviously after adding custom role for writting also).

Then I do not know why `DocumentDB Account Contributor` and `Cosmos DB Operator` does not work for creation database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks it is a bug in java SDK, the `DocumentDB Account Contributor` role is enough to create the database and container as it has the `Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/*` permission(`*` is a wildcard, it also includes the `Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata` you mentioned).

When I test to use a service principal with this role to create the database with the powershell [`New-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/new-azcosmosdbsqldatabase?view=azps-5.8.0), it works fine. When using the service principal to run this command, it essentially uses the [Azure AD client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, then uses the token to call the REST API - `PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/xxxx/sqlDatabases/testdb1?api-version=2020-04-01` to create the database, the [java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#in-java) essentially also does the same thing, so it should also work.

Comment: {...,"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.13.1 Windows10/10.0 JRE/11.0.10","statusCode":403,"resourceAddress" :"dev-sqlapi-acc-westus.documents.azure.com:443/…:"{\"code\":\"Forbidden\",\"message\":\"Request blocked by Auth dev-sqlapi-acc : The given request [POST /dbs] cannot be authorized by AAD token in data plane.\\r\\, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, StatusCode: Forbidden\",\"additionalErrorInfo\":null}","innerErrorMessage":"Request blocked by Auth dev-sqlapi-acc : The given request [POST /dbs] cannot be authorized by AAD token in data plane.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I logged to azure cli as service principal and I am able to create database with "az cosmosdb sql database create". Looks like bug.